# QTableWidget cell update

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

in Qt5.5 I have an QTableWidget. If I set cells text before compilation, everything is OK, but When I'm changing text in table when program is running, changes not showing. Could you help me with this?

To set text of cells I'm using:

```
ui->table->item(row, column)->setText("example");
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You used the class name instead of your object (instance) name (which shouldn't compile...).

If using the default name given by the form designer, the following code works:

```
ui->tableWidget->item(1, 1)->setText("example");
```

Note the use of `tableWidget` instead of `QTableWidget`.
Also ensure that you have correct values for row and column.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this bad, I'm setting this like you, it works in another part of my program, but there I'm using QTabWidget, and after change tab to another and back to tab with Table the new data is visible. If I don't using tabs, I don't see new data after setText and It is my main problem.

Comment: The QTabWidget should not change anything, the text should be updated straight away. Can you provide a bigger example, that would demonstrate this issue? This may be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve